# A better way to check whether multiple strings occur in a given cell

Tags: excel

In the past I have used `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*orange*",A1),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*apple*",A1)),1,0))` to check whether, in this case, orange or apple occurs anywhere in the cell A1.  If I wanted to check whether more strings were present I would need to keep adding more `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` lines.  For a large number of strings this is not feasible.  Is there a better way to do this without using VBA that I might be missing?

Comment: Are the strings in a range? E.g. orange and apple are in range C1:C2? If so, it can be shortened a lot.

Comment: @Jerry They aren't, but that was what I had in mind when asking if there was a better way.  If there are ways that don't involve having a separate list but allow all the keywords to be placed at once that would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this formula (note, you don't need to use the asterisk wildcard with `SEARCH`):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"orange","apple"},A1)))>0
```

This will give you `TRUE` if any of those two words are in A1. You can wrap it in an `IF` if you want a custom result message or use `MIN` to get 1 and 0:

```
=MIN(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"orange","apple"},A1))),1)
```

The formula works like this:

`SEARCH({"orange","apple"},A1)` looks for the words in A1 and returns an array of values if found, or error otherwise.

`ISNUMBER` checks each of these results in the array.

The two `--` at the front convert the TRUE and FALSE into 1 and 0 respectively.

`SUMPRODUCT` adds up those 1 and 0. If it is at least 1, you'll get a final result above 0.

Comment: I tried this out with two phrases (multiple words) rather than two words, but the first formula only returned zero despite the phrases being there.  Is there a reason there might be a discrepancy between the SUMPRODUCT formula and my formula?  Is there a difference when using multi-word phrases?

Comment: @114 You get TRUE or FALSE with the first formula. Otherwise, there should be no issues. Can you perhaps put your problematic string on [this GoogleSpreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/126Zx_asUsLjOpQDqfS6UWaPyKsV0qrFmfMznFHKagD8/edit?usp=sharing)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I realized I made a pretty silly error when typing everything in, thanks for your help Jerry!